# Docker machine switch to local docker

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am on Windows 10 Pro with Docker (not ToolBox) 
I have created two Docker machines on Virtual hosts using Hyper-V with the following commands

```
docker-machine create -d hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "vs-1" hyperv-vm-1
docker-machine create -d hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "vs-1" hyperv-vm-2
```

I can list the machines using docker-machine ls. I switch between the two docker-machine using

```
& "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker-machine.exe" env hyperv-vm-1 | Invoke-Expression
& "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker-machine.exe" env hyperv-vm-2 | Invoke-Expression
```

How can I switch back to my local Docker machine from these Virtual hosts ?
When I tried to search, I can see Linux/Mac equivalent, but not Windows. Any help appreciated

Comment: I think you need to unset the environment variables https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/#unset-environment-variables-in-the-current-shell and it will revert back to your default. It does say it is unsupported in Window...

Answer (score 0):

Just use this command:

```
& "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker-machine.exe" env -u | Invoke-Expression
```